# PyQt5 QTableWidget и перетаскивание изображений в ячейки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Мне нужно вводить путь к файлу в ячейку когда я перетаскиваю этот файл в QTableWidget.

Мне надо изображение перетаскивать и получать его путь потом вставлять его в ячейку.

Если можно то напишите программу.

Вопросы:
Как мне отследить перетаскивание в QTableWidget и ячейку в которую перетаскивается? Помогите пожалуйста :)

Тема закрыта спасибо. Я нашёл, 2 часа в гугле искал и нашел :)

Comment: если пользоваться гуглом, то один из вариантов реализации драг'н'дроп это первая же ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227885/drag-and-drop-rows-within-qtablewidget

Comment: Читай внимательней, мне надо изображение перетаскивать и получать его путь потом вставлять его в ячейку.

Comment: занимайся. здесь не бесплатный фриланс

Comment: Это малая часть моего большого проекта, и прошу объяснить, не обязательно делать программу. Я не знаю как здесь всё устроено, у меня значок новый участник. И я изучил python, 4 месяца назад и прошу объяснить.

Comment: И этого нет в гуле, я искал.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Тема закрыта спасибо. Я нашёл, 2 часа в гугле искал и нашел :)

Comment: Если вы нашли решение - опубликуйте его в ответ, может оно поможет другим при решении аналогичных проблем.

Comment: А как опубликовать ответ.

Comment: Мне надо 15 баллов репутации, а у меня их нет.